# Does Google+ have something similar to Facebook's groups?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like to discuss a certain topic with some people and have all posts related to that discussion in one place so they can be checked separately and not become lost in my feed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a workaround that might work for you

You could create a google+ site regarding the topic and add the contributing people to circles.

https://plus.google.com/pages/manage

http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1710599&hlrm=de&ctx=topic&answer=1710600

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The main thing I see missing is an inability to make the Google+ Page completely private..

Answer (score 3):

Google added a new feature called communities. I think this is better for your purposes.

https://plus.google.com/communities

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no such a product integrated with Google+. However, Google has a separate product [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/), which is just that: email-based discussion with archiving in a central place. The groups [can be private](http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46365) (i.e. inaccessible to non-members), if you wish so.